# write , instead of . in mathmode

Tags: macros

in my language it's typical to write comma in numbers instead of a dot (12,34 instead of 12.34). However, if I write ",", it automatically inserts space right after the comma. To overcome this, I have to write "{,}" instead. Is is possible to somehow convince latex to write "," instead of "." in mathmode?
Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. The packages `icomma` or `siunitx` may be of use to you!

Comment: Prefer `siunitx` over `icomma` please. Especially if you want to typeset some units, you will love to have it.

Comment: There's also `numprint`  that is babel-aware.

Comment: Your language is Czech as I can see from your profile. You can see page 41 of the book "TeX pro pragmatiky" https://math.feld.cvut.cz/olsak/tpp.html the paragraph "Desetinná čárka místo tečky".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is i[t] possible to somehow convince latex to write "," instead of "." in mathmode?

Yes, it's possible to convince LaTeX to *print* a comma with no space around it while you *write* with a usual dot. E.g., `2.718` will print 2,718 with the correct spacing. If you want the usual comma (with a space after it) you need to write a comma rather than a dot, e.g., `(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2` will print something like (1, 2) ∈ ℝ².

You only need the line @wipet said

```
\mathcode`\.=`\,
```

---

My original answer, which is much larger is this one

```
\mathcode`\.="8000
\begingroup
\catcode`\.=\active
\gdef.{\mathord{,}}
\endgroup
```

This defines `.` to be “math active”, so inside of math mode, LaTeX will look at its active definition and use it. So, I define `.` to be a `\mathord{,}` which is what you want, with no spaces. Of course you need, as I said before, to *write* the dot, and it will be printed in the .pdf as a comma correctly spaced.

Comment: There exists more simple solution: ``\mathcode`.=`,``. Then `$3.1415$` prints 3,1415 with correct spacing.

Comment: @wipet Didn't know that.

Comment: @wipet - Can you think of any downsides to making `.` a math-active character?

Comment: I mean that the effect is the same.

Comment: @Manuel - Can you think of downsides to making `.` a math-active character?

Comment: @Mico No idea, but at first sight there should be no problem (I'm not sure how it works, but I thought this was the way in spanish `babel` we can write `\spanishdecimal{.}` or `\spanishdecimal{,}`).

Comment: If the OP wants the comma to be the decimal marker on *output*, I suspect he/she is also very much in the habit of using the comma as a decimal marker on *input*, i.e., writing numbers as `123,346` -- bringing back the need to write `123{,}456` (or replacing all decimal commas with decimal periods, which might be a tedious affair...). The `siunitx`-based solution I've suggested treats both `.` and `,` as decimal markers on input.

Comment: @Mico Well, if my problem was that I was used to write `,` rather than `.` and the solution is `\num{123,456}` I definetly try harder to write `123.456` which does no harm (or even make a comma with no space and write `,\,` to separate in case I need it). By the way, `babel` does use some kind of `\mathcode` so I suspect it's similar to this (didn't look further).

Answer (score 10):

You have two well-established options:

- Load the [siunitx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx) package with the option `output-decimal-marker={,}`, and then write `\num{123,456}`. The option to treat `,` as the decimal marker carries over to numbers typeset in tables if the package's `S` column type is specified.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}  
  \begin{document}
  \num{123,456}
  \end{document}
  ```

  The instruction `\num` works in text *and* math mode. The package's other commands that can typeset numbers (and units, as in `\SI{9,81}{\newton\per\second\squared}`) also works in both modes.

  You didn't mention your language, but in case it's German you could also load the `siunitx` package with the option `locale=DE`. Doing so will automatically invoke the rule to typeset the decimal marker as a comma. As of September 2014, the package offers five language/region localizations: DE, FR, UK, US, and ZA (South Africa). If you'd offer to provide information to create a new localization (CZ, say), I'm sure the maintainer of the `siunitx` package would be delighted to hear from you.
- Back on the subject of typesetting numbers in tables, you could also use the [dcolumn](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools/) package and define your own column type, say `d`, as follows:

  ```
  \newcolumntype{d}[1]{,,{#1}}
  ```

  Then, in a `tabular` or `array` environment, use a column specification such as `d{2.5}` to inform LaTeX that the numbers in that column can have up to 2 digits before the decimal marker and 5 digits after the marker, which has been set to be a *comma*.

Comment: I would suggest to test first if there is a `locale` for the used language. Like `locale=DE`.

Comment: @Johannes_B - Thanks. I've added a paragraph to mention the `locale=..` possibility.

Comment: If I understand the question, the OP want to do less typing than `{,}` especially only dot. And you suggest to do more typing: `\num{1,2}` (four characters more than `{,}`).

Comment: @wipet - I'm absolutely no good at mind-reading, that's for sure. My impression, though, is that the OP would prefer to keep using commas as decimal markers in both input and output. The capabilities of `dcolumn`'s `d` column type and `siunitx`'s `S` column type for tabular material certainly make it easy to use commas as input decimal markers, *without* having to do anything special about the numbers (such as using a `\num` wrapper). And, if the numbers come in conjunction with units, then `\SI{<number>}{<unit>}` requires no extra typing either, whether commas or periods are used on input.

Comment: @Johannes_B locale=DE works great. i think this is the most convenient solution

edit: oops sorry, it doesn't. I didn't erase this line: \mathcode`\.=`\,
that's the code that makes it work

Comment: @Tom83B Trust me, it works: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[locale=DE]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num{12,35}
\end{document}
`

Comment: @Johannes_B my mistake, i didn't use the \num command. well, the solution with \mathcode`\.=`\, is much more convenient

Comment: @Tom83B Might be, but the `locale` switch does take care of other things as well.

Comment: The tenth upvote on this answer earned me my 400th badge on this site. Many thanks to the upvoter -- and to everyone who continues to make this site a great place!!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you only want to suppress the space, you can write `$12{,}34$`. This is what I mostly do if I feel that `siunitx` is an overkill (I'm a mathematician, I rarely work with units, however, I do work with floats).

Comment: If you work a lot with `tabular` and `array` environments, you should definitely acquaint yourself -- if you haven't already done so long ago... -- with the capabilities of the `S` column type of the `siunitx` package and the `d` column type of the `dcolumn` package.

Comment: @tohecz -- Yeah, I kind of suspected you were aware of it. :-)