# Space after comma in empheq package

Tags: spacing, punctuation, empheq

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
0,5
\begin{empheq}{align}
0,5
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Good (normal) is comma in first 0,5 .

[image]

But not good in **{empheq} package** 0,5 . It have a little space. I want to delete space.

[image]

I didn't find duplicate another question. So, does anyone know how to fix it?

Related to: [Space after comma in units package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154916/space-after-comma-in-units-package)

Comment: Use `0{,}5`.....

Comment: A workaround is `0{,}5`. The comma always inserts a small space because of the other uses, like `(a,b)`, or `\{0,1,2,3\}`. In any case, I would choose to *write* `0.5` and then change the output later. [Here is an option.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199181/21930)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `empheq`; in math mode, the comma is classified as punctuation, so TeX automatically adds a thin space after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do specifically with `empheq`. The simple document

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
0,5 $0,5$
\end{document}
```

will show the same behavior. In math mode a comma is a punctuation symbol, so TeX automatically adds a thin space after it, which is needed in formulas like `$(a,b)$`.

Either you use `0{,}5` in math mode, because this makes the comma into an ordinary symbol or use a dedicated package such as `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}
\num{0,5} or \num{0.5} % text mode

$\num{0,5}$ or $\num{0.5}$ % math mode
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the output is independent of whether you use a period or a comma in the input.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the space by putting comma inside braces like `0{,}5`. But it is better to use `siunitx`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
0,5
\begin{empheq}{align}
0{,}5\\
\num[output-decimal-marker = {,}]{0.5}
\end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Harish Kumar, I wrote about 60 pages. Approximately 600 commas. Is it macro possible, **comma**s only in empheq equation. *x,y --> x{,}y* Because I don't working your with siunitx package.